# Postgres: How to group a very large table and insert the results into a new table?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am working in Postgres 9.6 with PostGIS. I have a very large table (about 30GB):

```
                                       Table "public.parcels"
    Column    |          Type           |                            Modifiers
--------------+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------
 ogc_fid      | integer                 | not null default nextval('parcels_ogc_fid_seq'::regclass)
 wkb_geometry | geometry(Polygon,4326)  |
 county       | character varying       |
```

I would like to create a new table that contains one polygon per county, with the polygon being the union of that county's polygons. I have defined my new table as follows:

```
 gid      | integer                 | not null default nextval('newtable_gid_seq'::regclass)
 the_geom | geometry(Polygon,4326) |
```

I know how to insert one county at a time from the first table into the second table:

```
INSERT INTO by_county(the_geom) values 
  ((SELECT ST_Union(wkb_geometry) FROM parcels where county='Warwick'));
```

But how can I do this programmatically for all counties? My current approach is to write a Python script with psycopg2 that first retrieves the `DISTINCT` county names, and then runs the above command manually for each county: but I'm wondering if there's a less manual way.

As noted this is a large dataset, and I'm working on a machine with 16GB of RAM. So it may be that my one-command-at-a-time approach is the best after all?

Answer (score 1):

Since ST_Union is an aggregate function you can do a GROUP BY in your select

```
INSERT INTO by_county(county, the_geom)
   SELECT country, ST_Union(wkb_geometry) FROM parcels GROUP BY county
```

> As noted this is a large dataset, and I'm working on a machine with
>   16GB of RAM. So it may be that my one-command-at-a-time approach is
>   the best after all?

Probably not because postgresql is very good at handling large datasets. As a rule of thumb, one big query will be faster than a collection of small queries.

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately when I try that I get `SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Failed.` - I guess because of the large query?

Comment: Are you doing this from remote? SSH into the db machine and execute the query from there.

Comment: I'm doing it in a screen session, having SSHd into the remote machine. I closed the screen session and checked the database, no records had been added.

Comment: Sequence of events: (i) ssh into remote server (ii) start screen session (iii) run command, wait, see error in comment above (iv) open another ssh session and kill dead screen session (v) in new ssh session, check database, no records added. I think the local connection had died as you say, which is why I could only kill the screen session via another ssh session.

Comment: Is this one sorted out?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-copy.html) command. You can give this a shot

```
psql -d <DATABASE> -c "copy (SELECT country, ST_Union(wkb_geometry) FROM parcels GROUP BY county) to STDOUT" | psql -d <DATABASE> -c "copy by_county from STDIN"
```

You will have to make sure the columns that you specify are in order.